# Getting irregularities from java PDFBOX

Tags: java, pdf, latex, operators, pdfbox

I'm using Java PDFBOX 2.0.12 to try and read a latex generated PDF. everything seems to work fine but for some reason certain values(**<,<=,>,>=**) get changed to question marks(**?**), and i get various warnings such as **"WARNING: No Unicode mapping for a105 (105) in font F18"**. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Java code:

```
try {
        PDDocument document = PDDocument.load(file);
        PDFTextStripper pdfStripper = new PDFTextStripper();

          //Retrieving text from PDF document
          String text = pdfStripper.getText(document);
          System.out.println(text);

          //Closing the document
          document.close();
    } catch (InvalidPasswordException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Latex code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[a5paper]{geometry}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % font encoding
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\title{algorithmicx (algpseudocode) example}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithmic}[1]
\If{$quality\ge 9$}:
\State $a\gets perfect$
\ElsIf{$quality\ge 7$}:
\State $a\gets good$
\ElsIf{$quality\ge 5$}:
\State $a\gets medium$
\ElsIf{$quality\ge 3$}:
\State $a\gets bad$
\Else
\State $a\gets unusable$
\EndIf
\end{algorithmic}
\end{document}
```

document that is generated/used:https://drive.google.com/file/d/1P16FMHc1Pkd897G448Zd_6pgmnoWQLGt/view?usp=sharing

Comment: I get correct text extraction with the ExtractText command line utility - maybe write to a file and view it with an editor. I do get the errors, this is because your font uses non standard names for glyphs.

Comment: @TilmanHausherr is there a way to fix that?

Comment: Maybe it's a problem with latex: it creates type 3 fonts with bitmaps of the glyphs instead of using vector fonts (e.g. truetype or type1). Your PDF will look crappy at higher resolution, e.g. look at the "e" in "else" at 600% in Adobe Reader. Latex should also create valid glyph names, for "d" the glyph name is "d" and not "a100". (look at the font in PDFBox PDFDebugger) For some reason, "quality" is done with a type1 font which is fine, but "else" isn't.

Comment: @tilman Hausherr, so this is a PDF problem? Does PDFBOX allow me to say replace on font to another?

Comment: It is not a PDF problem. Replacing a font in a PDF would be getting extremely complex. Better solve this from the latex side, i.e. find out why "else" is printed using this bitmap font. This is so 80ies. Maybe create a new question with only the latex label and use my comments. Suggested title: "why is latex generating a bitmap font for my PDF?". Mention what software and what version is being used.

Comment: @TilmanHausherr but the "else" word is not creating any problems. the problem arises from the "<=" sign and so forth.

Comment: But you're getting the warning "No Unicode mapping for a115 (115) in font F18". The problem with the sign doesn't occur on my machine. I believe that this is just happening because your IDE can't display "≥". Try `System.out.println ("≥");` does it appear? That's why I said to write it directly into a file and display this file with a modern editor, e.g. NOTEPAD++.

Comment: @TilmanHausherr you're right, i couldn't even save the file when i copied and pasted System.out.println ("≥"); it kept giving me error **some characters cannot be mapped using "CP1252" character encoding. Either change the encoding or remove the characters which are not supported by the "CP1252" encoding**. i had to click the **"safe as UTF-8"** button. Printing it to a file also didn't help.

Comment: try `stripper.writeText( document, output );` with output being `new OutputStreamWriter( new FileOutputStream( outputFile ), Charsets.UTF_8 );`

Comment: @TilmanHausherr it didn't write anything? the output file was empty.

Comment: Did you close the file after finishing? If this doesn't work, try the ExtractText command line utility as part of the PDFBox-App.  https://pdfbox.apache.org/2.0/commandline.html#extracttext  Then look at the result txt file with an editor. This would show that it is possible.

Comment: @TilmanHausherr two things. your ode recommendation actually fixed the issue. the signs("≥", "←") can be seen in the output file. another solution i found was i opened the generated pdf in notepad++. the file encoding was set to ansi. after i changed it to UTF-8. the signs were properly written.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As discussed in the comments - the file should be written as utf8 and opened with a good editor like NOTEPAD++.

```
    try (OutputStreamWriter out = new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(txtFile), Charsets.UTF_8);
         PDDocument document = PDDocument.load(pdfFile))
    {
        PDFTextStripper stripper = new PDFTextStripper();
        stripper.writeText(document, out);
    }
```